# Xamarin - Storage data in smartphone memory

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am work with xamarin and I need to storage data in memory of my Android device. In order to have the data once the game has reopened. How can I do? where can I find an example code?

Comment: Depending on needs you could use either SQLite or SharedPreferences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on data type, structure and your specific needs the approach may vary. Since we are talking about a game most probably you need a database. Luckily the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/databases) nicely covering this topic.

Beside that if you using .NET Standard take a look on EntityFramework.

P.S.: Generally I would recommend to make a research (as the options above are not the only one) to compare existing solutions and than decide which way to go.

Answer (score 0):

[Akavache](https://github.com/reactiveui/Akavache) could be a good solution. It's fairly simple and flexible too.